# How to expand/shrink UICollectionViewCell height when a UITableview with dynamic cell height is placed inside?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView inside a UICollectionViewCell. I am loading a remote RSS feed to my tableview. Initially the UICollectionViewCell height is equal to the tableview height. However, when data is loaded and the cells in the tableview expand, the UICollectionViewCell does not expand.

Note: I am calling collectionView.reloadData() from the main thread so thats not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method to provide the new height after your table has been loaded:

```
- collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
```